# Dynamic parameters in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with a select count in my stored procedure, it looks like that when I use two dynamics parameters it refuse to works.

For example :

1.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO @var
FROM TMP_TABLE
WHERE UDA10 = 3;
```

Works perfectly

2.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO @var
FROM TMP_TABLE
WHERE UDA10 = @vlQuota
```

Works too

3.

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO @var
    FROM TMP_TABLE
    WHERE @llQuota = 3;
```

Doesn't work (always return 0)

4. (The one I want)

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO @var
   FROM TMP_TABLE
   WHERE @llQuota = @vlQuota;
   ```

Doesn't work (always return 0)

So the problem may be with the @llQuota parameter but when I check it returns "UDA10" like it should.

I also tried to execute the query with PREPARE and EXECUTE but I have the same problem.

EDIT : UDA10 is a column I put in example, it can be anything that why I use @llQuota and not directly UDA10. The problem may be that MySQL does not understand @llQuota is a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I had to use PREPARE and EXECUTE but I also had to concatenate the parameters :

Ex :

```
SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) into @nbExtract 
FROM TMP_EXTRACTION WHERE ', @llQuota, '= ', @vlQuota, ';');
PREPARE statement FROM @qry;
EXECUTE statement;
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO @var
FROM TMP_TABLE
WHERE if('UDA10' = @llQuota, UDA10 = @vlQuota, 1);
```

In your query @llQuota is a string so it can't be treated as a column. It behaves as a string.

Comment: The problem is I put UDA10 as an example so it can be anything. Is there a way to make MySQL understand @llQuota is a column and not a string ?

Comment: can you tell how you are setting \@llQuota, \@vlQuota

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
create PROCEDURE proc_count()
BEGIN
    declare var int(20)default 0;

    select count(*) as count into var from table1;

select var;

END
```

To call procedure:

```
call proc_count();
```